# Visual Studio generated Dockerfile does not work with manual docker build

Tags: docker, visual-studio, .net-core, dockerfile

I want to dockerize an existing .NET core 5 app and used the container tools to generate a Dockerfile. When I debug with Visual Studio 2022 it works but when I manually run it with the command `docker build -t some-name .` it generates the following error:

```
Step 7/21 : COPY ["MechEng.MovableBridges.Api/MechEng.MovableBridges.Api.csproj", "MechEng.MovableBridges.Api/"]
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat MechEng.MovableBridges.Api/MechEng.MovableBridges.Api.csproj: file does not exist
```

Why doesn't it find the file?

This is my Dockerfile that is inside the `MechEng.MovableBridges.Api` folder:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MechEng.MovableBridges.Api/MechEng.MovableBridges.Api.csproj", "MechEng.MovableBridges.Api/"]
COPY ["MechEng.MovableBridges.Infrastructure/MechEng.MovableBridges.Infrastructure.csproj", "MechEng.MovableBridges.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["MechEng.MovableBridges.MathCad/MechEng.MovableBridges.Infrastructure.MathCad.csproj", "MechEng.MovableBridges.MathCad/"]
COPY ["MechEng.MovableBridges.Application/MechEng.MovableBridges.Application.csproj", "MechEng.MovableBridges.Application/"]
COPY ["MechEng.MovableBridges.Domain/MechEng.MovableBridges.Domain.csproj", "MechEng.MovableBridges.Domain/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MechEng.MovableBridges.Api/MechEng.MovableBridges.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MechEng.MovableBridges.Api"
RUN dotnet build "MechEng.MovableBridges.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MechEng.MovableBridges.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MechEng.MovableBridges.Api.dll"]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your command fails, because the build context is wrong. Visual studio is using the solution root folder as build context, you are (probably) using the project's dockerfile's location. You can read more about the docker build command [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with-path).

Your command should look similar to this:

`docker build -f "<path-to-your-dockerfile>" -t some-name "<!!!path-to-your-solution-folder!!!>"`

You can see the exact command executed by visual studio in the output window, with "Container Tools" selected from the dropdown box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what should I do when I want a Dockerfile that also can be used without Visual Studio? When I want a Dockerfile for in a CI/CD pipeline? What is the workproces here?

Comment: The generated dockerfile can be used without visual studio, you just have to run the command you see in the output window I mentioned. The command you wrote: docker build -t some-name --> the problem is with the parameters, not the dockerfile

Comment: use the command like this: docker build -f "<path-to-your-dockerfile>" -t some-name "<!!!!!path-to-your-solution-folder!!!!!>"

Comment: Aah yes. You also edited your answer. I was also not reading the docs very well... This also explained from Microsofts docs how to run the Dockerfile from commandline. https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=visualstudio_containers_aka_containerfastmode#building-from-the-command-line. I will accept your answer for giving me the answer in a different form.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, you can move the docker file to one back folder.
For example, folder1/folder2/dockerfile move to folder1/dockerfile and build the image.

> Docker build -t  imageName .

> Docker run -p 7778:80 imageName

Answer (score 0):

For those of you trying to run your Visual Studio generated Dockerfile in an Azure pipeline using the Docker@2 task you need to set the buildContext on the task. In many people's cases this is probably the solution folder which contains your project and the other projects it references;

```
- task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: '<your container registry>'
        repository: '<your repository>'
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        Dockerfile: '*/<the start-up project>/Dockerfile'
        buildContext: '<Solution name>' <-- THIS
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```